# The Efficient way to sort a collection of Objects

Tags: java, database, collections

I have a requirement to sort a collection of objects, They are shown on a web page in tabular format. My sorted collection is created  like

```
TreeSet<MyObject> objs= new TreeSet<MyObject>();
```

Currently `MyObject` is implementing Comparable interface to provide sorting. In the `compareTo` method object is checked against the date of creation as my sorting logic.

Now I have got a requirement to sort this collection on the basis of various other instance variable of the class. After exploring options to achieve this I have got two ideas for this execution,

1. Use a `Comparator`. In this class I can implement my logic to sort the collection.
2. Create a database query to return the sorted collection for `MyObject`. I can use `ORDER BY` Optimization to achieve this.

So, I would like to know your opinion on the both approaches and what should be best optimum solution for such a requirement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you already have the objects in memory, then sorting them with a `Comparator` is definitely faster.

If you query them from the DB each time anyway, then using `ORDER BY` is definitely easier and probably faster as well.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer +1 w00w very nice and yet so simple answer